# The import "javax.jnlp" cannot be resolved

Tags: java, import, jnlp, java-web-start

I am learning Java and trying to run some examples using Java web start.

However, I cannot seem to find that package `javax.jnlp`.

This same error is haunting me on both windows and linux.I've installed oracle jdk 7 on windows.OpenJDK 1.6 is the version installed on linux.

Searching the internet for the package with no luck.It is no longer available on oracle's website because they insist that the package is a part of the jdk.

I've searched the installation directories for it.some claim it is in the `jnlp.jar` file, others claim in `javaws.jar` file...neither files are part of my installation.

Comment: Does this [demo. from the `BasicService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs)
build OK for you?  It specifies `<property name="classpath" value="${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar" />` *"they insist that the package is a part of the jdk."* And JRE.

Comment: It is part of the JDK, at least since about 1.4. If you're using an older version that doesn't contain it, update. It is way overdue.

Comment: Thank you all.I tried the BasicService demo that you provided Andrew.It worked.so i left it in memory and checked the commandline that was used to launch it (using Process Monitor).I found this command option "-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/netx.jar"..and that's where i found the javax.jnlp package.Including this "netx.jar" file in the project's build path solves the import problem.but isn't that strange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Oracle page:

> The jardiff tool, jnlp-servlet.jar file, and jnlp.jar file can be found in the samples directory of the JDK.

On my comp it is in:

`... /jdk1.6.0_23/sample/jnlp/servlet/jnlp.jar`

---

For Java 7 you have to download [Demos and Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) separately:

Windows x86 (32-bit)    15.62 MB      [jdk-7u4-windows-i586-demos.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u4-b20-demos/jdk-7u4-windows-i586-demos.zip)

Windows x64 (64-bit)    15.69 MB      [jdk-7u4-windows-x64-demos.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u4-b20-demos/jdk-7u4-windows-x64-demos.zip)

You will find jnlp.jar inside:
`jdk1.7.0_04\sample\jnlp\servlet\jnlp.jar`

Comment: The links have broken.

Answer (score 7):

Can be found in `jre/lib/javaws.jar` in 1.7 and 1.8, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555413/829305

The `jre/` directory can be found inside the `jdk/` directory if you've only got the JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to javaws.jar file in your classpath. For example: 
    "javac -classpath .:/path/to/javaws.jar webstart/*.java"